How do I use JSON functions on a generated column?
My schema:
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    json_data TEXT
);

The json_data column is of the format:
[
  {"key": "foo", "date": "2023-01-01"},
  {"key": "bar", "date": "2023-01-02"}
]

I can query the date of the first element that has "key": "bar":
SELECT (
    SELECT json_extract(value, '$.date')
    FROM my_table,
         json_each(my_table.json_data) AS each
    WHERE json_extract(each.value, '$.key') = 'bar'
    ORDER BY each.rowid
    LIMIT 1
) AS first_foo_date
FROM my_table;

Is it possible to use JSON functions on a generated column?

Generated columns can't use table valued functions like json_each(), or sub queries

I think the only option is to use a TRIGGER instead of a generated column.
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    json_data TEXT,
    date_from_json TEXT
);

-- Create a trigger to populate the date_from_json column
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Extract the date where key is 'foo' and set it to the date_from_json column
    SET NEW.date_from_json = (
        SELECT json_extract(value, '$.date')
        FROM json_each(NEW.json_data)
        WHERE json_extract(value, '$.key') = 'foo'
        LIMIT 1
    );
END;

-- Another trigger for updates
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Extract the date where key is 'foo' and set it to the date_from_json column
    SET NEW.date_from_json = (
        SELECT json_extract(value, '$.date')
        FROM json_each(NEW.json_data)
        WHERE json_extract(value, '$.key') = 'foo'
        LIMIT 1
    );
END;

